# SQL Union sort by Union

Tags: sql, sorting, sql-order-by, union

I have query

```
SELECT id, name 
  FROM users 
  WHERE id !=2 
UNION 
SELECT id, name 
  FROM users2 
  WHERE id != 3;
```

I want that sort will be, 1 union orders + 2 union it's possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a column to order on

```
SELECT id, name, 1 as unionOrder FROM users WHERE id !=2 
UNION 
SELECT id, name, 2 as unionOrder FROM users2 WHERE id != 3

ORDER BY unionOrder
```

Comment: +1. You may also find it's more efficient to use `union all` to avoid potential duplicate removal where duplicates probably cannot exists (eg, if `id` is unique key).

Answer (score 1):

You can as well do like

```
(SELECT id, name 
  FROM users 
  WHERE id !=2
ORDER BY id)
UNION ALL
(SELECT id, name 
  FROM users2 
  WHERE id != 3
  ORDER BY id);
```